# ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 2) are incompatible(Convolutional Neural Networks using keras and opencv)

Tags: python, opencv, keras, conv-neural-network

I am training a mask detection model(mask vs non-mask)using Convolutional Neural Networks on google colab. When I compile it, I am getting this error:

[image]

[image]

The relevant code is :

```
train_data,test_data,train_target,test_target = train_test_split(data , target , test_size =0.1)

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(200 , (3,3), input_shape = data.shape[1:])) 
#imageshape=100*100
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
#first cnn layer followed by relu and maxpooling layers

model.add(Conv2D(100,(3,3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))
#2nd cnn layer follwed by relu and maxpooling layers

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
#flatten layer

model.add(Dense(50 , activation='relu')) 
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
#dense layer of 50 neurons

model.add(Dense(2,activation= 'softmax'))
#the final layer with 2 outputs for two categories

#model compile
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy' , optimizer = 'adam' , metrics=['accuracy'])

#fit the model
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('model-{epoch:03d}.model',monitor='val_loss',verbose=0,save_best_only=True,mode='auto')
 history=model.fit(train_data,train_target,epochs=20,callbacks=[checkpoint],validation_split=0.2)
```

and the model summary is:

[image]

Comment: Show the shape of your data. Probably the issue is your Y shape is `(batch,)` i.e. it is only a single value for all the rows.

Comment: using the "print(data.shape) ", i got the shape of (1376, 100, 100, 1)

Comment: By data I meant the individual X-train, Y-train, X-test, Y-test.

Comment: here i used  train_data,test_data,train_target,test_target for train_test_split.now i get the shape of train_data =(1238,100,100,1) and train_target = (1238,)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output shape of your model is `(None,2)`

```
model.add(Dense(2,activation= 'softmax'))
#the final layer with 2 outputs for two categories
```

The shape of your Y data (label data) is as you mentioned in the comment `(1238,)` (I am referring to `train_target`)

The design of your Model's output shape must match the Y-data's shape.

For this particular case, you have a **Binary** classification problem and your data is probably having the values `0 or 1` i.e. shape = `(None, 1)`. But the last layer of your model outputs an array with shape `(None, 2)`.

My suggestion would be to change you model to output only 1 value instead of 2.

Code Change for Model:

```
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
#the final layer with 2 outputs for two categories
```

Code Change for Compilation:

```
#model compile
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy' , 
              optimizer = 'adam' , metrics['accuracy'])
```